# output string "nan" if value is 0

Tags: c++, stream

I need to output a number, unless it is 0, in which the output has to be "nan"
I can't do

```
int x;
...
cout << (!x ? "nan" : x);
```

since the types in ternary expressions do not match. I can do

```
void f(ostream& o, int x)
{ 
    if (!x) o << x;
    else o << "nan";
}
```

which looks a bit ugly to me. Is there a better solution to this?
Something, like

```
cout << nanify(x);
```

maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not saying I would do it that way but you *could* install a custom `std::num_get<char>` facet to print `nan` when a `0` is printed:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

class zero_num_put
    : public std::num_put<char> {
    iter_type do_put(iter_type out, std::ios_base& str, char_type fill, long v) const {
        if (v == 0) {
            static char nan[] = "nan";
            return std::copy(nan, nan + 3, out);
        }
        return std::num_put<char>::do_put(out, str, fill, v);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::locale loc(std::locale(), new zero_num_put);
    std::cout.imbue(loc);
    std::cout << 0 << " " << 17 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's actually quite informative. I am not sure I'd go with it, but it looks like "the right" general solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use this:

```
int x;
...
cout << (!x ? "nan" : std::to_string(x));
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an option, though not very efficient, right? I mean converting to a string before piping to the stream

Comment: In terms of Big O computation it should not be more expensive/slower than what you are currently doing depending on how to_string is implemented. From a software engineering perspective it is much cleaner than creating a new function. Is microsecond speed a requirement for what you are doing?

Comment: I am just looking for "the right way" to do it. Not sure, what you mean by Big O here, but I think, it considerably slower, say, than my ugly function, because you are creating a string object every time you get a number.

Comment: @LazyCat: reasonable `std::string` implementations use the small string optimisation and creation of the `std::string` is unlikely to cause much of an overhead. I could imagine that you can't tell the difference between both approaches.

Comment: What is "the right way", if I can I want to suggest to you a couple of books every software engineer should read: 1. Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code by Martin Fowler  and 2. Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship by Robert C. Martin

Comment: @KwekuReginaldWade: "THE right way": see my answer! ;-)

Comment: @KwekuReginaldWade Thanks, I've upvoted you answer, but will accept the other one, as it explains the general setting to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something along those lines:

```
std::string nanify(const int x) {
    if (x) { /* If not 0, return 'x' as a string */
        return std::to_string(x);
    }
    /* Else, return "nan" string */
    return "nan";
}

std::cout << nanify(0) << ' ' << nanify(15); /* nan 15 */
```

Comment: thanks, but I think, it's even worse than my solution :)

Comment: What exactly looks worse to you ?

Comment: That on top of my function you create a temp string object.